I'm searching for the title of an episode film or the title of the special episode - genres: mystery / horror / science fiction
I'm looking for a movie I watched quite a few years ago either on TV or on video tape. I would classify it published between 1980 and 2000. The film wasn't a blockbuster almost certainly and may not even ran at the cinemas.
The film consists of at least two completely different stories; one episode is about aliens who land on earth - maybe alien abduction is also theme of this episode (which I don't remember...).
The episode I remember was arranged in style of a police documentation. Scene is a lonely house or farm, farmstead respectively. Due to an emergeny call a task force is send to this building. The building seems to be empty, anyhow the task force is send into the building to find the committer of the call inside. The operational forces are wearing bodycams - so most of the footage they send to the outside is blurred. Dialogues mostly take place via radio. After a while a part of the emergency services in the attic of the building finds a part of the roof broken; it snows in through the holes in the roof, although it does NOT snow outside the building. I remember a radio message from "outside" to the emergency services in the attic, which read something like this: "You have already gone so far - you can not really stay INSIDE 
the building any more..."
Unfortunately, I do not remember the end of this episode - and that's why I'm looking for the title of the film / series episode.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

You mention an alien landing and police procedural themes. Did the aliens remain on earth and one of them become the partner of the main human cop? Were the aliens hairless with spotted patterns on their scalps?
You may be thinking of Alien Nation. It consists of a film, TV series, and several direct to TV movies. The two main characters are a human named Matt Sikes and his alien "Newcomer" partner George Francisco. The main plot follows the two of them as they pursue murders and disappearances involving the Newcomers. One of the TV movies involved a cult leader using an alien hypnotic device to enter a shared hallucination with her victims. The climax sees her leading the main characters into an abandoned warehouse that looked like a paradise while in the hallucination, which reminded me of the strange weather properties mentioned in the question.
The name of this particular film was Alien Nation: Millenium.

Hello and welcome!   You might want to edit the first paragraph of your answer so that it doesn't look like you're asking additional questions in your answer.   It will help to get a better response.   Just a suggestion  :)
